# Is there an elegant way to store an ontology graph and the definitions/data associated with nodes?

Tags: perl, graph, ontology

I have written a simple module to store and manipulate an ontology which is provided in a flat file using Perl. For this, I use the [Graph module](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Graph/) which is excellent.

One issue I am having to deal with is how to store the textual definitions for the vertexes in the ontology. Each term has a small text description which I want to store and retrieve. At the moment, as Graph does not support this directly, I use an internal hash.

I was wondering, is there a more elegant way of having a single data structure to store both the ontology graph *and* the definitions/data associated with nodes?

Comment: Bioinformatics or semantic Web?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`Graph`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Graph) module allows you to attach [attributes](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Graph/lib/Graph.pod#Attributes) to the vertices and edges. Is that what you mean when you say you are currently using an internal hash? If not, perhaps this will help:

```
use Graph;
my $g = Graph->new;

my ($v1, $v2) = qw(A B);
$g->add_edge($v1, $v2);

$g->set_vertex_attribute($_, 'desc', "Vertex $_") for $v1, $v2;
print $g->get_vertex_attribute($_, 'desc'), "\n"  for $v1, $v2;
```

Answer (score 8):

Following things come to mind:

- if this is just a "simple ontology", i.e. a taxonomy, or even simpler, a
  nested list of terms, then
  a simple [YAML](http://p3rl.org/YAML::Any) file sounds sufficient. Once deserialized into a Perl hash,
  you have mapped any nesting into hashes/arrays.
- if you want your ontology (dictionary, subterms, superterms) to be more
  standardized you may want to look at [RDF::SKOS](http://p3rl.org/RDF::SKOS). [SKOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SKOS) is the W3C standard
  for simply (non-logic) ontologies.
- if you are daring, you may also want to look at [TM](http://p3rl.org/TM) ([topic maps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topic_Maps)). It has a
  similar "functionality" as SKOS, but is an ISO (not W3C) standard.
- if you expect your ontology to grow/evolve and also hold simple logic statements
  (see [Description Logics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Description_Logics)), you may want to look at one of the RDF packages. I
  have used [RDF::Redland](http://p3rl.org/RDF::Redland), but also [RDF::Simple](http://p3rl.org/RDF::Simple) or what [Toby](http://search.cpan.org/~tobyink/) and [Kjetil](http://search.cpan.org/~kjetilk/) do, are
  worth trying. Lots of activity recently.
- if your ontology is BIG, or you want to store A LOT of instance data alongside
  your ontology, then [RDF::AllegroGraph](http://p3rl.org/RDF::AllegroGraph) is the way to go. But that uses an external
  server. Serious software.

Parting note: Not everything which looks like a graph is one. Neither Topic Maps nor RDF are
graph structures actually.

Comment: Is it possible/advisable to store a Topic Map as a graph? Like if I had a fast graph-database, could  n-ary relationships be emulated with artificial nodes?  If not, what is the best way to store a topic map? (when files seem too slow and a high performance persistant solution is needed)

Comment: I have read the Topic Maps Reference Model (tmrm) and now understand that graphs are probably a bad idea for topic maps. so sets and maybe assertions are better.